# Вывод произвольных подразделов каталога Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Как сделать вывод произвольных подразделов каталога Битрикс. Использую bitrix:catalog.section.list, но он выводит первый уровень каталога и все подряд. Мне же нужно выборочные категории вывести. Может где из ID указать?

**UPD**

```
Структура такая:
Категория 1
  Подкатегория 1
  Подкатегория 2
  Подкатегория 3
Категория 2
  Подкатегория 1
  Подкатегория 2
  Подкатегория 3
Категория 3
  Подкатегория 1
  Подкатегория 2
  Подкатегория 3
```

Нужно вывести подкатегории определенные из разных категорий. По возможности, просто указав их ID

Answer (score 1):

Для вывода произвольных разделов стоит обратиться к методу [`CIBlockSection::GetList`](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblocksection/getlist.php), которому в параметре `arFilter` передаете ID разделов, которые хотите вывести. Затем выводите полученные данные так как Вам нужно или можно вызвать его в файле `result_modifier.php` компоненты, чтобы отфильтровать список разделов для вывода.

В том месте где хотим вывести нужные разделы каталога вставляем такой код:

```
<?php
$rsSections = CIBlockSection::GetList(
    array("SORT" => "ASC"),
    array("IBLOCK_ID" => $IBLOCK_ID, "ACTIVE" => "Y", "ID" => $SECTION_IDs),
    false        
);
while ($arSections = $rsSections->fetch()) {
    /*        
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($arSections);
    echo '/<pre>';
    */
    //выводите нужную информацию так как Вам надо, например
    <a href="<?= $arSections['SECTION_PAGE_URL'] ?>">
        <?= $arSections['NAME'] ?>
    </a>
}
?>
```

Comment: А можно кодом помочь, что-то у меня не получается((

Comment: Добавил пример. Было бы неплохо если бы в вопросе показали, что вы делаете и что не получается.

Comment: Нужно на голавной вывести некоторые из категорий. Они каждая в свобю очередь находятся в разных категориях.

Comment: ну тогда пользуйтесь примером, что я набросал. id разделов вы знаете или их тоже нужны получить?

Comment: А сами ID я где-то должен вписать? "IBLOCK_ID" => $IBLOCK_ID - здесь просто через запятую?

Comment: `ID" => $SECTION_IDs` вместо `$SECTION_IDs ` указываете `array(1,2,3)`, где `1,2,3` id нужных разделов

Comment: Согласно моему UPD в вопросе - указывать ID нужных подкатегорий?

Comment: да, в вашем случае передаете id подкатегорий

Comment: Спасибо, попробую - отпишусь.

Answer (score 0):

У вас только два выхода, либо кастомизация компоненты list, либо шаблона компоненты

Comment: Так вот и хотел бы узнать как))

Comment: @Batyabest завтра напишу пример кода

Comment: Добрый день. Напишите, пожалуйста, пример кода, а то сложновато мне((

Comment: @Batyabest ой, извините, заработался вчера, но обещание выполню.

Comment: @Batyabest вам нужно только разделы фильтровать и любой глубины?

Comment: Добавил UPD в сам вопрос